# Zend form - why does validation fail?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a password field that is required in the form:

```
$pwd = $this->CreateElement('password', 'pwd')
        ->setLabel('Change Password')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(6, 16))
        ->addValidator('regex', false, array('pattern' => $allowed_pattern))
        ->addErrorMessages(array(
            'regexNotMatch' => "Only alpha-numeric characters and some punctuation are allowed.",
        ))
        ->addFilter('StringTrim');
```

But in the case of an EDIT to the form, I don't want to require this field. There I use:

```
    $form->getElement('pwd')->setRequired(false);
```

in my controller before passing the form to the view. When I check the properties of this form element, I have _allowEmpty set to 1 and _required set to 0. However when the form is submitted (with empty field) it fails validation on this field and returns the error message for the RexEx validator above.

Any ideas why field fails validation under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Still you can improve the method of creating form element,

1. Remove the `setRequired(true)` here and mention true or false where you want use this form element(I think you are specify to true and false for the same element).
2. When you submit empty form it is returning `addValidator('StringLength', false, array(6, 16))` error because,
3. if you specify `addErrorMessages()` function it disables all other validator messages and retures its array messages and  because you forgot to mention add error message element for string lentght.

Look at the follow example to and try to apply it for you case.

```
$samplepassword=$this->createElement('samplepassword','samplepassword');
    $samplepassword->setLabel('Password')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
            ->addValidator('StringLength',false,array('min'=>6,'max'=>16,'encoding' => 'UTF-8','messages'=>array(
                                            'stringLengthTooShort' => 'Passwords must be 6 char mi',
                                            'stringLengthTooLong' => 'Passwords must be no longer 16 something like that'
                                        )))
            ->addValidator('regex', false, array('pattern' => $allowedstring,  messages'=>array('regexNotMatch'=>'Passwords should alphabet or something')));
```